# How to remove the marker from the cluster in google map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-markers

I have implemented `cluster` in google map and I want to update the map with the `markers` based on the checkbox selection.

I want to remove the marker from the cluster based on the custom property that I have set in the marker.

> var clust = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {maxZoom: 14});

How can I do this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each marker to remove:

```
 clust.removeMarker(marker);
```

For each Marker to add:

```
 clust.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: I have included a custom Info to the marker and I want to remove those that does not contain the custom info. So how can i do this?

Comment: I actually want to show and hide the marker based on the checkbox selection and so I tried remove marker but on removing I could not add it. So is it possible to set visible true and false, so it would remain in the array and just be hidden.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I don't have the removed marker data to add it again. So I have used setVisible(true/false) and it appears and disappears on checkbox toggle. I have one more doubt and which is I have a search box too in the map where I should be able to filter  the markers based on the search. I am working on it and if you could tell me how I can do this, it would be helpful.

Comment: yes, you must keep all your markers all the time. Just hide/show on map and clusterer. For a search input, I'd consider fetching new markers directly from server

Answer (score 0):

You need to set map null for current markercluster and then create new marker array on the basis of property you want then create new markercluster again and set to map.

```
var clust = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {maxZoom: 14});
```

on update property

```
clust.setMap(null)
var newclust = new MarkerClusterer(map, newmarkers, {maxZoom: 14});
newclust.setMap(mapobject)
```

Comment: I wouldnt recommend to create objects each time

Comment: Remove and add marker on the basis of condition is more time consuming then. Just remove all markers and create new cluster. In this way we need to iterate only once

Comment: yes you are right. But sometime if number of markers is too high then. User experience also affect due to extra looping time. Both the strategy have some side effect :)

Comment: think twice: what do you think the clusterer does with the array you pass to it? yes it will loop.