# How to remove one marker from markerCluster

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, markers

I am using Ionic 3 with @ionic-native/google-maps (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md).

I am using markerCluster to populate the map with markers.

At the moment, to update the markers, I am performing a `map.clear()`, as it can be seen in the code below.

The problem I have is that the markers are "flashing" when the map is clearing and the new one are created. By "flashing", I am trying to say that you can see how it disappears and appears again.

Is there a way to remove a marker from `markerCluster`, instead of clearing the map?

I am using this code to show on map some locations with some updates.

E.g.:

- the pin is green if available
- the pin is blue if in used
- remove pin if offline

So, I am calling the WS to get the status every few seconds and update the pins icons based on the status.

I have tried `markerCluster.remove()`, instead of `map.clear()`, but the pin is not removed from the map.

```
this.map.clear();
markerCluster = this.map.addMarkerClusterSync({
    markers: this.markers,
    icons: [
           {
             min: 2,
             max: 9,
             url: this.assetsPath + "images/pin_cluster.png",
             label: {
                    color: "black",
                    fontSize: 15,
                  },
             size: { width: 40, height: 40 }
            }],
              boundsDraw: false
            });
```

Comment: Instead of clearing the map, set that specific marker's map to null. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249870/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-cluster-icons

Comment: You could also use `markerCluster.removeMarker`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302466/how-to-remove-the-marker-from-the-cluster-in-google-map